# How to add recent elements in an array by removing the old elements with a limit of 5?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arraylist

consider the below array, i want to add an element to the starting of this array and at the same time pop the last element.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

so the result array should be

```
arr = [6,1,2,3,4]
```

And i should be able to add the element in an array only if the length is less than 5.

Comment: why is the length relavant, if you keep the length? btw, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
let a=[1,2,3,4,5];
if(a.length<=5){
    a.unshift(6)
    a.pop();
}
console.log(a) // [6, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new items and remove the old ones passing the new elements and remove the same quantity of elements using `slice`:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let limit = 5;

function addItems(items) { //<-- elements you want to add
  return [...items, ...arr.slice(items.length - 1, limit - 1)]
}
console.log(addItems([6]))
```